# Magmi- products are assigning to new categories instead of existing categories

Tags: magmi

we are using magmi to import products and also we are assigning products to categories using csv format as below :

```
sku::categories

sku1::Mobile Cases and Covers/Photography/Apple iPhone 4
```

products are uploading fine, but instead of assigning to exisitng categories, its creating new categories and assigning products to new categories.

[image]

Comment: Try with applying category ID rather then name.

Comment: @KaushalSuthar we have 1000's of categories, we need some permanent solution

Comment: Can please provide your sample CSV format with few data?

Comment: @KaushalSuthar please click here and download the file : http://www.filedropper.com/666666

Comment: @KaushalSuthar it is happening for only for old subcategories, i created new sub category and uploaded, its working fine. means its assigning products to new sub categories.

but if i enter old subcategory names, its creating new sub-categories.

Comment: once i renamed the categories to something and again if i rename with same name, its working fine. thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a category branch does not exist, it will be created on the fly during the import process and your products will be assigned to it. Maybe any typo in your category name. Just check once again and for more details,
http://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-on-the-fly-category-creator/

Comment: i cross checked category name, it already exists , but still its creating new category with same name. please check updated question.

Comment: As you said `Mobile Cases and Covers` categories are created again. Is that category created under `Default Category` or somewhere else?

Comment: its created under default , please check image in question

Comment: please click here and download the file : http://www.filedropper.com/666666

Comment: I tried with your file and it works perfectly. seems like problem is not in csv. maybe in magmi configuration. can u post the screenshots of all categories before and after import.

Comment: before : http://prnt.sc/bmx7yw

after : http://prnt.sc/bmx806 , you can see`Photography` sub-category is present on top in first image. but still it created on bottom in 2nd image

Comment: http://prnt.sc/bmxejn when i uncheck the `On the fly category creator/importer v0.2.4` , and uploading excel sheet. now new categories are not creating.
but products are not assigned to existing categories.

Comment: 'On the fly category creator/importer v0.2.4' is responsible for creating & mapping the categories. So removing that will not make any sense. How did you configured in magmi for the same?

Comment: okay than i will add it again.

Comment: please check magmi configuration : http://prnt.sc/bmyp0o

Comment: it is happening for only for old subcategories, i created new sub category and uploaded, its working fine. means its assigning products to new sub categories.

but if i enter old subcategory names, its creating new sub-categories.

Comment: once i renamed the categories to something and again if i rename with same name, its working fine. thanks for your support

Comment: i need to rename al categories , we have thousands of categories, is there any other solution ?

Comment: I don't know why it is happening but you can make a try to add products with respect to different sub categories. Like, first add products of `Apple iPhone 4` of `Photography` category by changing `base category tree` to `Mobile Cases and Covers/Photography` in configuration. If it works, it might reduce your work